# Removing NA rows from specific column from all dataframes within list

Tags: r

I want to remove any row if there is an NA entry within the column called "name" from all data frames within a list.

Here is the list:

```
points <- feature_list %>% sapply(., "[[", "osm_points" )
```

Each element within "points" is a data frame with a column labeled "name."

I would like to subset "points" so that each date frame contain rows with entries other than NA in the names column.

Comment: Share (a sample of) your data using `dput`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` or `purrr::map`:

```r
ll <- list(df1 = data.frame(name = c(1, NA, 1), a = letters[1:3]),
     df2 = data.frame(name = c(1, 1, 1), a = c(1, NA, 1)),
     df3 = data.frame(name = c(1, NA, 1), a = LETTERS[1:3]))

lapply(ll, \(x) x[!is.na(x$name), ])
#purrr::map(ll, ~ .[!is.na(.$name), ])

# $df1
#   name a
# 1    1 a
# 3    1 c
# 
# $df2
#   name  a
# 1    1  1
# 2    1 NA
# 3    1  1
# 
# $df3
#   name a
# 1    1 A
# 3    1 C
```

data

```r
# $df1
#   name a
# 1    1 a
# 2   NA b
# 3    1 c
# 
# $df2
#   name  a
# 1    1  1
# 2    1 NA
# 3    1  1
# 
# $df3
#   name a
# 1    1 A
# 2   NA B
# 3    1 C
```